# Were New Testament writers infallible when they wrote Scripture?

Tags: bible, infallibility, biblical-reliability

Were New Testament writers infallible when they wrote Scripture, inspired through the Holy Spirit?

Thank You.

Comment: Is your question the same as asking whether the texts of the New Testament are infallible? Or do you mean something different? Which denomination's perspective are you inquiring about?

Comment: No, I'm asking that were New Testament writers infallible when they wrote the Bible, and as a Catholic, I believe Holy Bible is Infallible

Comment: So whether they were infallible in other things they wrote? In their general actions? Do you want the Catholic Church's answer to his question then?

Comment: This is a matter of _faith_ , not of physical proof or of liturgical enforcement. None of the NT writers actually make such a claim. But if one receives a witness of the Holy Spirit (to oneself, personally) then one is encouraged to receive their words as dependable, authoritative, accurate and inspired. Peter testifies such of the epistles of Paul.

Comment: Consider asking from a particular Christian background, because what Catholics, evangelicals, and mainline protestants mean by infallible is significantly different.

Comment: @curiousdannii No Only the Writing of Scripture

Comment: @ninthamigo Amen to that.  Hence my answer showing how Catholics and Protestants answer the OP's question differently.  My answer deals with the OP's question as it is (unscoped), so it's all good.  Maybe someday I'll add the Eastern Orthodox view to the answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Inspired, Inerrant, Infallible

Let's be careful about the usual meaning of those 3 technical terms as they are generally used in Christianity, with different shades of meaning according to the different denominations, esp. between Catholics and Protestants.  For a general overview, please consult the relevant *wikipedia* articles for [Biblical inspiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_inspiration), [Biblical inerrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_inerrancy), and [Biblical infallibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_infallibility).

For simplicity, [this handout](https://www.northcoastcalvary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Class-1-Inspiration-Infallibility-Inerrancy-Handouts.pdf) captures the general meaning succinctly:

1. **Inspiration**: about *origin* affecting the **author**: "From God"
2. **Inerrancy**: about the *truthfulness* of the **text**: "Without error"
3. **Infallibility**: about the *authority* on the **reader**: "Without fail"

Your question

> Were New Testament writers infallible when they wrote Scripture, inspired through the Holy Spirit?

then contains a misnomer.  While you are correct in using the terminology that the writers (the **author**) are **inspired** by God, it is incorrect to use the term "infallibility" to refer to the author, because in general use, "infallibility" means how the Bible produces the effect of being able to be received by the **reader** as authoritative teaching.

#### Illumination and the Holy Spirit

Now let's think how *exactly* the Bible can be *infallible*, especially when there are multiple interpretations?

Protestants have different answers than Catholics:

- For Protestants, who all hold *sola scriptura*, the effect of the Bible being authoritative (infallible) to the reader is due to the Holy Spirit **illuminating the reader**.  In other words, the Bible's authority and enduring nature (i.e. infallibility) cannot be separated from the faithfulness of the Holy Spirit teaching the reader *through* the Bible.  It's the Holy Spirit that leads the reader toward accepting what the Bible says as true teaching from God.  That's why Protestants believe in private interpretation of Scripture because there is the Holy Spirit who teaches.
- For Catholics, they point to the evidence that Protestants interpret Bible differently so they question whether that's REAL infallibility.  Instead they
  assign infallibility to the teaching office of the Church due to the Holy Spirit **illuminating the Magisterium**.  While the Catholic church doesn't exclude the Holy Spirit illuminating individual Christians, the Catholic church teaches that when there is conflicting interpretations, the Magisterium is the one infallibly guided by the Holy Spirit.

#### Conclusion

Were the New Testament writers *infallible* when they wrote Scripture?  **Technically, No**.  They are *inspired* when they wrote Scripture.  The Scripture becomes *infallible* when either the Holy Spirit or the Magisterium teaches the correct interpretation to individual believers.  **BUT for Catholics** since the several New Testament writers were ALSO bishops (Magisterium), Catholics can say that **they were infallible when they *taught*** their own writings to the original audience, since their own writings that later became canonized are about **faith and morals**, the only kind of teachings that are deemed infallible.

Were they *infallible* when they do anything else?  Protestants answer **No**, Catholics answer **Yes**, because there are *some* unwritten teachings of the apostles (about **faith and morals**, not skills as tentmaker, doctor, tax collector, carpenter, etc.) that were infallible *to the original audience* and were handed down through generations to become the [Apostolic Tradition](https://www.catholic.com/tract/apostolic-tradition).  The Apostolic Tradition becomes infallible *to Catholics today* [as taught and interpreted by the Magisterium](https://wherepeteris.com/the-perspicuity-of-tradition/), similar to how Scripture becomes infallible *to Catholics today* through the same teaching office.

For Catholics, both the Scripture and the Apostolic Tradition form the [single sacred deposit of faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposit_of_faith) that has been interpreted and transmitted *infallibly* by the [Magisterium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magisterium) (the pope and the bishops) down through the ages until today.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to [the Chicago statement](http://www.bible-researcher.com/chicago1.html), which is widely regarded as the definitive text on the subject of Biblical inerrency:

> Holy Scripture, being God's own Word, written by men prepared and superintended by His Spirit, is of infallible divine authority in all matters upon which it touches. Holy Scripture [...] may properly be called infallible and inerrant

This applies to both the New *and Old* testaments.

The Bible itself affirms this belief (2 Timothy 3:16):

> All Scripture is breathed out by God and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, and for training in righteousness

For a more complete answer, I recommend reading the Chicago Statement itself.

Comment: Widely regarded as definitive? By whom? This document came out in 1978.

Comment: @Alex, that sounds like a good follow-up question. As to the date, why is that an issue? According to [this article](https://www.gotquestions.org/Chicago-Statement-Biblical-Inerrancy.html), though, a good first-pass answer would be "several hundred Christians representing forty-one churches and thirty-eight Christian denominations".